# How to inject static class in Spring-Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-storage

This question was asked a lot of times. I am bit confused and hope your ideas.

I am integrating Google Cloud Storage in Spring-Boot.

I have config class.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "gcs.credentials")
public class  GCSConfig {

    private String serviceAccountId;

    //...
}
```

Storage factory which implements singleton pattern.

```
@Component
public class StorageFactory {

    @Autowired
    private static GCSConfig gcsConfig;

    private static Storage instance = null;

    public static synchronized Storage getService() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = buildService();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private static Storage buildService() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {

        HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
        // ...
        // I use gcsConfig here
        // ...
        return new Storage.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
        .setApplicationName("Google Cloud Storage App")
        .build();
    }
}
```

And I use StorageFactory in the `service` like that.

```
Storage client = StorageFactory.getService()
```

I have read that `Autowired` doesn't inject static members. Is there another  way to implement it? Maybe here Spring-Boot's features which create singleton easily.

What should I read? Could you give me links? Can you guide me in the right direction?

Link for the [GCS examples](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-java-samples).

Comment: Are you aware that the default scope of spring beans is "singleton"? As such, it doesn't make a whole lot of sense to implement the singleton pattern in a class that is to be exclusively used as a Spring bean.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend not using static methods for this purpose. If you are using Spring Boot it would be better to use a [configuration class](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-configuration-classes.html) to inject a singleton scoped `Storage` instance:

```
@Configuration
public class StorageServiceConfiguration {

  private GCSConfig gcsConfig;

  // I prefer using explicit setters for testing, YMMV
  @Autowired
  public void setGcsConfig(GCSConfig gcsConfig) {
    this.gcsConfig = gcsConfig;
  }

  @Bean
  public Storage getStorageService() {
     // Logic to create your Storage instance.
     return new Storage.Builder(...) ...;
  }
}
```

Depending upon what you're doing with `GCSConfig` you could just inject the property values or the Spring Boot `Environment` into the `StorageServiceConfiguration` class, and skip the intermediate object.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to inject static classes. Injection implies that an instance has been created. Your referencing class just has to use the `import static ...`

Answer (score 1):

You can perform this operation as following way and it could best fit in your usecase

Step 1: create new class that will able to return instance of bean class

```
package com.xyx;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    private ApplicationContextProvider(){}

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public  static <T> T getBean(String name,Class<T> aClass){
        return context.getBean(name,aClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) throws BeansException {
        context = ctx;
    }
}
```

Step 2: create your own configuration class where your config properties are bind

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "gcs.credentials")
public class  CloudConfig {
    private static CloudConfig objectInstance=null;

    private String serviceAccountId;

    public String getServiceAccountId() {
        return serviceAccountId;
    }

    public void setServiceAccountId(String serviceAccountId) {
        this.serviceAccountId = serviceAccountId;
    }

    public static CloudConfig getInstance(){
        if(objectInstance==null){
            objectInstance=ApplicationContextProvider.getBean("cloudConfig",CloudConfig.class);
        }
        return objectInstance;
    }
}
```

Finally now whenever you need configuration class instance just invoke
`CloudConfig.getInstance()` method and access all the required data using gettter and setter of that class

`get more detail about bean injection` [click here](http://www.jhaji.in/2016/03/getting-bean-manually-in-spring-boot.html)

I hope it will help you out. Thanks.